# How can i get Path Name From My Current Drectory using RecursiveIteratorIterator Class in PHP

Tags: php, php-7.2

I am Working in Magento 2.3 i Want to get All flies from a Directory

> http://localhost/magento23/pub/media/catalog/product

i am using RecursiveIteratorIterator class when i use getPathName()
i got

> /var/www/html/magento23/pub/media/catalog/product/m/h/mh12-green_main.jpg

```
public function scd($path)
    {
        $di       = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
        $files    = [];
        $allowed  = ['jpg'];
        foreach ($iterator as $file) {
            $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
                $files[] = $file->getPathName();
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }
```

i want the path after

> catalog/Product

folder something like

> /m/h/mh12-green_main.jpg

how can i do this

Comment: what is the problem you're encountering?, looking at the code, i think this should work okay getting the absolute path

Comment: i am getting `/var/www/html/magento23/pub/media/catalog/product/m/h/mh12-green_main.jpg` but i need `/m/h/mh12-green_main.jpg` only

Comment: i have done that using `explode()` but i if their is any predefined funtion to get path after current directory it would be much better

Comment: there's no built in function to cherry pick which path you need to have as a return value. its either you trim the path using your input path as basis, or what you already have done which is to explode it

Comment: okay thank you that all what i need to know